# Take all input in Python (like UAC)

Tags: python

Is there any way I can create a UAC-like environment in Python? I want to basically lock the workstation without actually using the Windows lock screen. The user should not be able to do anything except, say, type a password to unlock the workstation.

Comment: I have researched. I know about LockWorkstation from ctypes, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: by "not be able to do anything" do you mean you want to disable all function keys and special keys (such as ctrl-alt-del on windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get the effect you desire using a GUI toolkit that draws a window that covers the entire screen, then do a global grab of the keyboard events. I'm not sure if it will catch something like ctrl-alt-del on windows, however.

For example, with Tkinter you can create a main window, then call the `overrideredirect` method to turn off all window decorations (the standard window titlebar and window borders, assuming your window manager has such things). You can query the size of the monitor, then set this window to that size. I'm not sure if this will let you overlay the OSX menubar, though. Finally, you can do a `grab` which will force all input to a specific window.

How effective this is depends on just how "locked out" you want the user to be. On a *nix/X11 system you can pretty much completely lock them out (so make sure you can remotely log in while testing, or you may have to forcibly reboot if your code has a bug). On windows or OSX the effectiveness might be a little less.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this without cooperation with operating system. Whatever you do, Ctrl-Alt-Del will allow the user to circumvent your lock.

Comment: How could I cooperate with the OS with Python? Or, rather, how might I go about disabling Ctrl-Alt-Del or the Task Manager?

Comment: Why would you want to disable the Ctrl-Alt-Del or the Task Manager?  Those mechanisms are essential for the user to kill rogue programs, eg. trojans that impersonate workstation locks and seek to steal passwords.

Comment: You can lock workstation in a proper way following instructions given here: 

    `import ctypes
    ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation ()`

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/lock_my_workstation.html 
But this will show the default lock screen, which you want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The API call you're looking for Win32-wise is a combination of [`CreateDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetThreadDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In terms of the internals of Vista+ desktops, [MSDN covers this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx), as does [this blog post](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops). This'll give you the requisite background to know what you're doing.

In terms of making it look like the UAC dialog - well, `consent.exe` actually takes a screenshot of the desktop and copies it to the background of the new desktop; otherwise, the desktop will be empty.

As the other answerer has pointed out - Ctrl+Alt+Delete will still work. There's no way around that - at least, not without replacing the keyboard driver, anyway.

As to how to do this in Python - it looks like pywin32 implements [SetThreadDesktop](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/PyHDESK__SetThreadDesktop_meth.html) etc. I'm not sure how compatible it is with Win32; if you find it doesn't work as you need, then you might need a [python extension](http://docs.python.org/extending/) to do it. They're not nearly as hard to write as they sound.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with pygame, because it can lock mouse to itself and thus keep all input to itself, but i wouldn't call this secure without much testing, ctr-alt-del probably escape it, can't try on windows right now.

(not very different of Bryan Oakley's answer, except with pygame)